# Recursive Submenu Opening and Incorrect Active Class Assignment on Right Arrow Key Press

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, treeview, submenu, arrow-keys

I'm currently working on a web application that has a menu system with submenus. I'm trying to implement arrow key functionality where the right arrow key should open a submenu, and the active class should be assigned to the corresponding link. However, I'm encountering an issue where pressing the right arrow key is opening all submenus recursively and incorrectly assigning the active class to multiple links. I've provided the relevant code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {// Other functionality code...
$(document).keydown(function(e) {const activeLink = $('.main-link.active');const submenu = activeLink.next('ul');
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: // Left arrow
        if (submenu.is(':visible')) {
          submenu.slideUp();
        }
        break;
      case 39: // Right arrow (not working as intended)
        if (!submenu.is(':visible')) {
          submenu.slideDown();
        }
        break;
      case 38: // Up arrow. functionality
        if (activeLink.parent('li').prev('li').length > 0) {
          activeLink.removeClass('active');
          activeLink.parent('li').prev('li').find('.main-link').addClass('active');
        }
        break;
      case 40: // Down arrow functionality
        if (activeLink.parent('li').next('li').length > 0) {
          activeLink.removeClass('active');
          activeLink.parent('li').next('li').find('.main-link').addClass('active');
        }
        break;
    }
      $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function () {
        // Toggle menu-open class
        $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
        // Toggle title
        if ($('body').hasClass('menu-open')) {
          $(this).prop('title', 'Collapse Menu');
        } else {
          $(this).prop('title', 'Expand Menu');
        }
        // Close all child menus
        $('.treeview-menu').slideUp();
      });
  
      // Handle menu item clicks
      $('.main-link').on('click', function (event) {
        const clickedLink = $(this);
        const isActive = clickedLink.hasClass('active');
  
        // Remove active class from other items
        $('.main-link.active').removeClass('active');
  
        if (!isActive) {
          // Toggle current item
          clickedLink.addClass('active');
        }
  
        // SlideToggle and SlideUp for submenus
        clickedLink.next('ul').slideToggle();
        clickedLink.parent('li').siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
      });
});
```

When I press the right arrow key, instead of just opening the submenu associated with the active link, it's opening all submenus recursively and assigning the active class to multiple links. I tried many. different solutions and even

```
activeSubMenu.find('.main-link:first').addClass('active');
```

does not seem to work. I'm not sure what's causing this behavior. Could anyone help me identify the issue and provide a solution to achieve the desired functionality? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Here is the HTML code associated with this. I forgot to add it in the post here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Navigation Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="treeview">
        <li class="main-link">
            <a href="javascript:">
                <i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i>
                <span>Warehousing</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu menu-open">
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="javascript:" class="main-link">
                        <span>Setup</span>
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu menu-open">
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/division/division-list">Division</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/branch-plant">Branch/Plant</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/warehouses-stores">Warehouses & Stores</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/inventory-types">Inventory Types</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/container-type">Container Type</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/location-type">Location Type</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/location-level">Location Level</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/operation-codes">Operation Codes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/resources">Resources</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/company-calendar">Company Calendar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/purchase-exception">Purchase Exception</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="/warehousing/setup/warehouse-location">Warehouse Location</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- New Inventory Module -->
        <li class="main-link">
            <a href="javascript:">
                <i class="fas fa-cubes"></i>
                <span>Inventory</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu menu-open">
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="/inventory/stock-levels">Stock Levels</a>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="/inventory/audit-trail">Audit Trail</a>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="/inventory/reports">Reports</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not angular. Do a functional example for us.

Comment: It seems to be... jQuery, right? Please, fix the tagging. Also, provide a functional example, an executable snippet or at least provide your HTML so we can have a better context and try it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just added the relevant html code that I forgot to add earlier and modified the tags. Is this sufficient enough or would you need more context on the problem?